# Clear search field not removing form data

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-easyui

I am using Jquery, I have a input type of text for searching values and a button to clear the search string.

The problem I am having is when I clear the search field when I click clear search button, value in input text is getting cleared, however the form data is not getting cleared, in browser console I can see the input text I have used in search field.

The following code is used for clearing values in input text

```
$(':input','#myform')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .removeAttr('selected');
```

I have tried using

```
$( '#myform' ).each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```

However it didn't solve the problem either.

How can I clear the input text field as well as form data when I click clear search button?

Form elements

```
<form id="myform">
<input id="desc">       
<a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="getSearch()">Filter</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton"
onclick="removeFilter()">Clear</a>  
</form>
```

**Edit 1**

```
function getSearch(){
            $('#dg').datagrid('reload',{
                desc: $('#desc').val(),
                            search: 'true',                                
                            loadValues: 'false'
            });
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by form data

Comment: When you submit the form, is the value of search field send to server? I think that it is console behaviour that will not take effect when you remove the field text from it with javascript.

Comment: @ArunPJohny What I meant by form data is data being sent to server. When I press clear button, I can still see value being sent to server and I can print the values in server even though input field text is getting cleared.

Comment: @Mojtaba What I meant by form data is data being sent to server. When I press clear button, I can still see value being sent to server and I can print the values in server even though input field text is getting cleared.

Comment: how are you getting the data to be sent

Comment: are you serializing the form

Comment: @ArunPJohny Sorry I didn't get your question

Comment: please paste your whole code here. easyer to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is your clear search button type `submit` or could the send form event be somehow attached to it by `id` or `class`? Check the jQuery Form plugin. It has for example reset and clear form functions. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

Comment: @Yordi I have added my form element code in my question.

Comment: @ZZ-bb I am not using button type of submit, I have included my form element code in my question.

Comment: can you share the `getSearch` method

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have added getSearch method as Edit 1. Thanks

Comment: Can you add a `console.log($('#desc').val())` in `$('#desc').val()` to see the value

Comment: I wonder how the data from `<input id="desc">` is being sent to the server as it doesn't have `name` attribute at all.

Comment: @ArunPJohny $('#desc').val() is null when I clear search input string.

Comment: that means the problem is with datagrid not with form reset

Comment: @ArunPJohny I too suspected this, but one thing is `desc` is not a part of datagrid, it is defined above the datagrid. So I am not sure how it passes the value to server.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean the fields and the form by using something like the following:

```
function clearForm() {
    // restore comboboxes to original value
    $("form select").each(function(){
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          $(this).val($("#"+id +" option:first").val());
          $(this).trigger("change");
    });

    // empty form fields
    $("#myform").find(":input[type=text]").val("");
    $('.combo-value').each(function() {
        $(this).val("");
    });
    $('#myform').find(':checked').each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
    // clear dateboxes - do not delete either line!
    $('.easyui-datebox').each(function(){
            //just type something random to force the hidden field to update
        $(this).datebox('setValue', 'dummy');
        $(this).datebox('setValue', '');
    });
}
```